# GUI delay after signing in - eOS 6

Tags: release-odin

Edit 2:

The issue is not solved because the delay happens after the boot. Boot is very fast and has always been; the issue starts when I log in with my password and only after that the system shows a blank screen with only mouse pointer visible. It delays 30 seconds to show the desktop and it wasn’t even my fault because I thought I screwed up the system and I installed eOS from scratch and guess what, it is still happening. Pretty annoying situation but on a second thought I guess the latest update is responsible for this. Before that, everything was perfect.

Original post:

*I tried to install Vocal Podcast Player .deb file (older Elementary package), but it refused to be installed and shown as broken package. So naturally I purged the broken packages and tried to fix it with `sudo apt update --fix-missing`, and it actually did fix the packages I guess, however when I sign in, the desktop now shows up with 30 seconds delay. Every single time this happens. I don't know what is broken but I need a guide.*

Edit 1: As per suggestion, I did an analyze. Now what am I supposed to do?

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @26.110s
└─multi-user.target @26.109s
  └─kerneloops.service @26.092s +15ms
    └─network-online.target @26.087s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.737s +24.349s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.476s +259ms
          └─dbus.service @1.467s
            └─basic.target @1.439s
              └─sockets.target @1.438s
                └─uuidd.socket @1.438s
                  └─sysinit.target @1.432s
                    └─swap.target @1.432s
                      └─dev-mapper-cryptswap.swap @1.409s +21ms
                        └─dev-mapper-cryptswap.device @1.408s
```

Comment: Vocal is available on AppCenter as a non-curated app. That's the best way to install it.
Having said that, you can use the command `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to know what is delaying the boot.

Comment: @Maccer the problem is that the delay happens after the boot is completed. I mean, the computer boots, I sign in but the desktop doesn't show up immediately.

Comment: @Maccer I updated my post with your suggestion. Could you point me to the next direction?

Comment: So basically the system is waiting for a internet connection to load the desktop. The solution is to disable that service with `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`.

Comment: Okay I did that and now the problem is 

graphical.target 1.867s
└─lightdm.service 1.755s +109ms
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service 1.726s +18ms
    └─nss-user-lookup.target 1.868s
And I can't disable lightdm (for obv reasons)

Comment: You now have a 2 second boot time. I think the issue is solved.

Comment: @maccer The issue is not solved because the delay happens after the boot. Boot is very fast and has always been; the issue starts when I log in with my password and only after that the system shows a blank screen with only mouse pointer visible. It delays 30 seconds to show the desktop and it wasn’t even my fault because I thought I screwed up the system and I installed eOS from scratch and guess what, it is still happening. Pretty annoying situation but on a second thought I guess the latest update is responsible for this. Before that, everything was perfect.

Comment: I have this problem too. It's a bug I think.